# How to jest mock nestjs imports?

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I want to write a unit test for my nestjs 'Course' repository service (a service that has dependencies on Mongoose Model and Redis).

courses.repository.ts:

```
    import { Injectable, HttpException, NotFoundException } from "@nestjs/common";
    import { InjectModel } from "@nestjs/mongoose"
    import { Course } from "../../../../shared/course";
    import { Model } from "mongoose";
    import { RedisService } from 'nestjs-redis';


    @Injectable({}) 
    export class CoursesRepository {

      private redisClient;
      constructor(
        @InjectModel('Course') private courseModel: Model<Course>,
        private readonly redisService: RedisService,
      ) {
        this.redisClient = this.redisService.getClient();

      }


      async findAll(): Promise<Course[]> {
        const courses = await this.redisClient.get('allCourses');
        if (!courses) {
          console.log('return from DB');
          const mongoCourses = await this.courseModel.find();
          await this.redisClient.set('allCourses', JSON.stringify(mongoCourses), 'EX', 20);
          return mongoCourses;
        }

        console.log('return from cache');
        return JSON.parse(courses);
      }
}
```

The test is initialized this way:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
    imports: [
      MongooseModule.forRoot(MONGO_CONNECTION,  { 
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
      }),
      MongooseModule.forFeature([
        { name: "Course", schema: CoursesSchema },
        { name: "Lesson", schema: LessonsSchema }
      ]),
      RedisModule.register({})
    ],
      controllers: [CoursesController, LessonsController],
      providers: [
         CoursesRepository,
         LessonsRepository
        ],
    }).compile();

  coursesRepository = moduleRef.get<CoursesRepository>(CoursesRepository);
  redisClient = moduleRef.get<RedisModule>(RedisModule);

});
```

My Course repository service has 2 dependencies - Redis and Mongoose Model (Course).
I would like to mock both of them.

If I was mocking a provider I would use that syntax:

```
providers: [
    {provide: CoursesRepository, useFactory: mockCoursesRepository},
     LessonsRepository
    ],
```

Can I create a mock Redis service which will be used instead of the an actual Redis service during a test?

How ?

Thanks,
Yaron

Comment: Can you show the code of your `CoursesRepository`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can mock your `RedisService` just as any other dependency. Since you are really interested in the Redis client and not the service, you have to create an *intermediate* mock for the service. For mongoose, you need the `getModelToken` method for getting the correct injection token, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52890134/4694994):

```
const redisClientMockFactory = // ...
const redisServiceMock = {getClient: () => redisClientMockFactory()}

providers: [
  { provide: RedisService, useValue: redisServiceMock },
  { provide: getModelToken('Course'), useFactory: courseModelMockFactory },
  CoursesRepository
],
```

Please also note, that you probably should not import modules in unit tests (unless it is a testing module). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55181691/4694994) on a distinction between unit and e2e tests.

### How to create mocks?

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55366343/4694994).

Answer (score 11):

Note that the accepted answer mocks a provider, which will satisfy the dependencies of your class under test IF it is also supplied from the `TestingModule` with a provider. However, it's not mocking `import`s as asked, which can be different. E.g. if you need to `import` some module which also depends on the mocked value, this will NOT work:

```js
// DOES NOT WORK
const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [
    ModuleThatNeedsConfig,
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: ConfigService, useValue: mockConfig },
    ExampleService, // relies on something from ModuleThatNeedsConfig
  ]
}).compile();
```

To mock an `import`, you can use a `DynamicModule` that exports the mocked values:

```js
const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [
    {
      module: class FakeModule {},
      providers: [{ provide: ConfigService, useValue: mockConfig }],
      exports: [ConfigService],
    },
    ModuleThatNeedsConfig,
  ],
  providers: [
    ClassUnderTest,
  ]
}).compile();
```

As that's a bit verbose, a utility function such as this can be helpful:

```js
export const createMockModule = (providers: Provider[]): DynamicModule => {
  const exports = providers.map((provider) => (provider as any).provide || provider);
  return {
    module: class MockModule {},
    providers,
    exports,
    global: true,
  };
};
```

Which can then be used like:

```js
const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [
    createMockModule([{ provide: ConfigService, useValue: mockConfig }]),
    ModuleThatNeedsConfig,
  ],
  providers: [
    ClassUnderTest,
  ]
}).compile();
```

This often has the added benefit of letting you `import` the module for the class under test, rather than having the test bypass the module and `provide` the value directly.

```
const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
  imports: [
    createMockModule([{ provide: ConfigService, useValue: mockConfig }]),
    ModuleThatNeedsConfig,
    ModuleUnderTest,
  ],
}).compile();

const service = module.get(ClassUnderTest);
```

Comment: Thanks, great use of dynamic module here. I had a very complex module that had a forward ref dependency on a 3rd party dynamic module, AgendaModule, which needed a value that was not possible to provide in test cases. Your solution helped me nail it. I used dynamic module and bypassed Agenda module from its imports, keeping other imports intact. And, also provided mock custom provider for the associated service.